# How do I prevent ActiveSupport using units, tens, and hundreds localisations in number_to_human?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, activesupport

I've set up a custom locale to get ActiveSupport to use short suffixes when calling `number_to_human`. Instead of `number_to_human(123456) => '123.4 Thousand'`, it gives me `number_to_human(123456) => '123.4k'`.

This all works fine. What *doesn't* work is that while the default locale would leave smaller numbers alone (i.e. `number_to_human(56) => 56`), my custom locale doesn't. I've left the suffixes for units, tens, and hundreds blank, but this results in `number_to_human(52) => '5.2'` (i.e. 5.2 tens) or `number_to_human(123) => '1.23'` (for 1.23 hundreds).

How do I tell ActiveSupport not to use units, tens, or hundreds at all - to just leave numbers under 1000 alone?

Here's the locale file, if it helps (`config/locales/en-ABBREV.yml`):

```
en-ABBREV:
  datetime:
    distance_in_words:
      x_seconds: '%{count}s'
      x_minutes: '%{count}m'
      about_x_hours: '%{count}h'
      x_hours: '%{count}h'
      x_days: '%{count}d'
      x_weeks: '%{count}w'
      about_x_months: '%{count}mo'
      x_months: '%{count}mo'
      x_years: '%{count}y'
  number:
    human:
      unit: ''
      ten: ''
      hundred: ''
      thousand: 'k'
      million: 'm'
      billion: 'b'
      trillion: 't'
      quadrillion: 'qd'
```

And my calls to `number_to_human` in the view look like this:

```rb
number_to_human @posts.count, precision: 1, significant: false, locale: 'en-ABBREV',
                units: 'number.human', format: '%n%u'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the docs of that method I think you can define the unit you want to use like the following. When a key (like `tens`) is not included in the `units` then that units will just not be used.

```
number_to_human(
  @posts.count, 
  format: '%n%u',
  precision: 1, 
  significant: false
  units: {
    thousand:    'k',
    million:     'm',
    billion:     'b',
    trillion:    't',
    quadrillion: 'qd'
  }
)
```